# Unable to delete openshift application

Tags: openshift

I installed a PHP application on one of my gears in Openshift. It is a git clone from https://github.com/ThinkUpLLC/ThinkUp/tree/v2.0-beta.10. Something went wrong with the application and hence I would like to delete this application now. However I get an error as "Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running." while trying to delete the application using rhc command tool. I have already tried using rhc app-force-stop, however it did not make any difference.

Comment: If you can't get it deleted please us the "contact us" form at help.openshift.com and we'll get it fixed.

Comment: I could do it later using the web console. Thank you for the support! For details please see my comment to the answer by @Hardy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a bit like this bug - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=997008. There seems to be no solution/workaround though.

Have you tried deleting the application via the web console?

Comment: Initially I tried deleting the application from the web console multiple times but I was getting a notification similar to one mentioned here : https://forums.openshift.com/cant-delete-applications-help. Then I tried deleting the application using rhc and I was getting the error as mentioned in the original question. After multiple failed attempts to delete the application using rhc, I switched to the web console again and this time I could delete the application easily. Looks like a bug in openshift?

Comment: I have the same issue. Reported at: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1224429

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command, this will kill all the background processes associated with the app.

```
pbrun /usr/sbin/oo-admin-ctl-app -l svc-<domain-id> -c destroy -a <app-name> -n <domain-id>
```